# Summing over numpy array with modulo

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

Consider the following setup:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
A = np.random.rand(3,3,3,16,3,3,3,16)  # sum elements of A to arrive at...
B = np.zeros((4,4))  # a 4x4 array (output)
```

I have a large array 'A' that I want to sum over, but in a very specific way. 'A' has a shape of (x,x,x,16,x,x,x,16) where the 'x' is some integer.
The desired result is a 4x4 matrix 'B', which I can calculate via a for-loop like so:

```
%%timeit
for x1,y1,z1,s1 in it.product(range(3), range(3), range(3), range(16)):
    for x2,y2,z2,s2 in it.product(range(3), range(3), range(3), range(16)):
        B[s1%4, s2%4] += A[x1,y1,z1,s1,x2,y2,z2,s2]

>> 134 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

where the elements of B are "modulo-4" of the two axes with 16 elements in that dimension in 'A', here indexed by `s1` and `s2`.

How can I achieve the same by broadcasting, or otherwise? Obviously with larger 'x' (dimensions in 'A'), the for-loop will get exponentially longer to compute, which is not ideal.

**EDIT:**

```
C = np.zeros((4,4))
for i,j in it.product(range(4), range(4)):
    C[i,j] = A[:,:,:,i::4,:,:,:,j::4].sum()
```

This seems to work as well. But still involves 1 for-loop. Is there a way to make this any faster?

Comment: You can do `A.reshape(4*n*n*n, 4, 4*n*n*n, 4).sum(axis=(0, 2))`. Not really faster, though.

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's a pretty clean solution, I like it :). Though: I tried `%%timeit` on your solution, it gives me about 1ms per loop. whereas my edited solution gives me about 0.5ms per loop.

Comment: Yep, I see essentially the same, @Troy. Seems to be an offset, though, rather than a factor, so it's probably some fixed overhead somewhere.

Comment: Working with NumPy, the important loops to push into NumPy are the inner loops. A 16-element outer loop in Python is probably fine. At that point, the dominant source of overhead is probably the NumPy implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a cleaner and a faster solution. Unfortunately, they are not the same ...

```
def clean(A):
    return A.reshape(4*n*n*n, 4, 4*n*n*n, 4).sum(axis=(0, 2))

def fast(A):
    return np.bincount(np.tile(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), (4, 4)).ravel(), A.sum((0,1,2,4,5,6)).ravel(), minlength=16).reshape(4, 4)
```

At `n==6` `fast` is about three times faster.

Comment: that works for me (incidentally, I am handling a matrix where n=6 so this works nicely). thanks!

Comment: you can do kind of a mix between you two solutions:  `C = A.sum(axis=(0,1,2,4,5,6)).reshape(4,4,4,4).sum(axis=(0,2))` and it's not too bad for performance